# Cloudinary rails integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, avatar, cloudinary

I am trying to use carrierwave with cloudinary to handle photo uploads and storage.Uploading an image seems to work fine as i get a url after upload but I cannot get the uploaded image to actually show. Visiting the image url also does not show anything either

Index view code

```
<td><%= image_tag(post.avatar_url) if post.avatar? %></td>
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the cl_image_tag?

`<td><%= cl_image_tag(post.avatar_url) if post.avatar? %></td>`

More info [here (see step 4)](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_integration)

Comment: If you look in you "Media Library" on the Cloudinary dashboard is the image actually uploaded?

Comment: Ah well that's probably the fist place to start. Once you have that figured out I remembered another bit about the `cl_image_tag` it takes just the last bit of the image url so it would be something closer to this: `= cl_image_tag("v1375414819/seeiw7xvqb8qlasmlmjv.jpg")` as opposed to the full url. Good luck!